# Facebook App - profile tab does not load

Tags: facebook

I'm writing a new facebook application with all migrations enabled. The canvas page loads. Profile page (fbml) doesn't load. When accessed page loads with the facebook ajax loader animated icon and just hangs there indefinitely. Facebook is not hitting my public server for the profile tab page. I've a servlet that can handle both GET and POST at this url.

The app canvas page is accessible at http://apps.facebook.com/sensei-shelf
The app profile  page is mapped to [canvasUrl]/profile.html and is accessible at apps.facebook.com/sensei-shelf/profile.html

I've set this as the profile page in my application's settings page. The profile servlet is capable of taking both GET and POST requests. The application is hosted on Google AppEngine. So from logs,  I know there is no incoming requests from facebook when a user clicks on the profile tab of the app.

The profile tab default column is to wide.

Any solutions/suggestions/workarounds please?

Regards,
Krishna

Comment: It's working for me now, I had to accept the permissions and then I see and empty wood bookshelf .. is this question still open ?

Answer (score 0):

When I visit http://apps.facebook.com/sensei-shelf/profile.html I get blank output.  Did you try that and verify that you can see requests coming in when a user loads the `profile.html` via a canvas url (http://apps.facebook.com/sensei-shelf/profile.html)?  Maybe Facebook is having problems resolving your domain?  Seems weird that the FB proxy servers wouldn't be able to get to your application at all...

Comment: I did try that. The requests were not landing on my server. Anyways, now facebook has deprecated the profile tab. So the question is not relevant any more...

Comment: Wow. I didn't even notice the age on this question. Sorry :P